# I'll reel you one in for the next window

Tags: word-meaning

Source: [1]: https://vm.tiktok.com/ZM8TWDvQb/

A McDonald drive-thru tiktok video went viral recently. The staff on the speaker was amazing doing his job. When he asked what drink the customer wanted for the meal, he went like:

Oi oi Saveloy, what drink do you like for that bad boy?

When the customer ordered two "7-up", he said:

That's 14-up.

When the customer asked "no lettuce please"， he went like:

No lettuce, no worries.

When the customer ordered "chocolate milk shake", he said：

Choccy shake. Don't mind if i diddly-do.

When the customer was at the finished ordering, the staff on the speak said:  I'll **reel you one in** for the next window my friend.

Did he mean "I will enter everything you ordered into the system so the next window can follow-up"?

Is it a funny way or a common way when a fast food company worker communicates with customers?

Comment: I wouldn't say that he was amazing, the non-standard English he was using sounds very unprofessional to me and, if he communicates with his colleagues like that it must drive them to distraction. I can't make up my mind whether he thinks that that style of communication is popular with his customers or whether, as I suspect, he's bored by the job. It might work for some customers but I think it would annoy more of them than it pleases.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a nonsensical scenario involving completely nonstandard speech. This particular McDonalds sales assistant is ***not*** someone you should think of copying!

Comment: The subtitles are wrong. The McDonald's employee says, "*I'll reel you into the next window*"

Comment: I’m closing this question because it's based on incorrect subtitles.

Answer (score 2):

This is **not** a common way to respond to a fast food order. Indeed I've never heard anything remotely similar at an actual fast food place. It is not at all clear what the server meant. Quite likely the server meant "your order will be ready at the next window". I strongly suspect this was a deliberately unusual or "funny" way of speaking. I would not advise a learner to try to imitate it.

The phrasal verb "reel in" is mostly derived from fishing, where a fisher having caught a fish on the hook, reels it in so that it is pulled out of the water by cranking the reel so that the line is wound up on it.

This has been extended to metaphorical use is several ways. It can mean "to pull something closer to oneself.  It can also be used to mean "to get someone involved in some sort of situation or scheme, often by slow steps". Frequently this latter meaning is used when the situation is a scam and the person being "reeled in" is a victim.

The use of "reel in" by the server does not seem to be any of the usual uses of this verb. The exact intent is unclear to me.

**Update**

I watched the video. which doesn't provide any particular clarification, except it confirms that the server is intentionally playing with language in non-standard ways. What if anything, the server specifically means by "reel" is still not clear, it may mean "I'll get that order for you".

Comment: Please edit the transcribed quote into the question, rather than just citing an extrenal link.

Comment: Yes the post has been updated with a more detailed transcription.